# how to call a function until I got the value? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to display the initial data without selecting the dropdown option to fetch data at the first time when the webpage is loaded. so basically I have three component which are:

```
Menu.js (parent component)
MenuLeft.js (sub component)
MenuRight.js (sibling component of MenuLeft)
```

In my Menu.js , I have two states and a function something like

```
const [menu, setMenu] = useState()
const [menuNumber, setMenuNumber] = useState(0)

FetchData(reg) {
  fetchReqs(para, reg).then(res => setMenu(res))
}

return (
  <>
    <MenuLeft MenuNumber={MenuNumber} setMenuNumber={setMenuNumber} />
    <MenuRight Menu={Menu} MenuNumber={MemuNumber} />
  </>
)
```

so my question is that the menu state was still undefined when the first time pass to MenuRight, by default the MenuLeft should have MenuNumber "1" and pass back to Menu component and get the Menu data ready and pass to MenuRight component to display something. How do I make the screen to load the MenuNumber as 1 and display the data in MenuRight component when the first time the web page load without I selected the menu number from the dropdown list in MenuLeft component, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving a default value to the `menu` state. You can do that by giving the default state to the `useState` function call like so:

```js
const [menu, setMenu] = useState("your default here");
```